# Gamma function $\Gamma (\alpha)$ is for $\alpha>0$ but how do we calculate value of gamma function at $-1/2$? Is not contradicting the definition?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

Gamma function $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is defined for $\alpha>0$ but how do we calculate value of gamma function at $-1/2$? Is not contradicting the definition?

Comment: it is the 1st example of [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). for $Re(s) \in (-1,0)$ : $\Gamma(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{s}$, and you have to show it stays analytic on $Re(s) > -1, s \ne 0$, so that extending $\Gamma(s)$ by a Taylor series around $s= 1/2+i t$ would yield the same result

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the definition of $\Gamma(s)$ by the functional equation $\Gamma(s + 1) = s\Gamma(s)$. Setting $s = -1/2$, we get $\Gamma(1/2) = (-1/2)\Gamma(-1/2)$, or $\Gamma(-1/2) = -2\Gamma(1/2)$. Since $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$, then $\Gamma(-1/2) = -2\sqrt{\pi}$.